# gensim doc2vec Model doesn't learn some words

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I'm currently learning gensim doc2model in Python3.6 to see similarity between sentences.
I created a model but it returns `KeyError: "word 'WORD' not in vocabulary"` when I input a word which obviously exists in the training dataset, to find a similar word/sentence.
Does it automatically skip some words not very important to define sentences? or is that simply a bug or something?
Very appreciated if I could have any way out to cover all the appearing words in the dataset. thanks.

Comment: In the default settings, words with frequency < 5 are not included in the vocabulary. Could that be the case?

Comment: @sg.sysel thanks! yeah could be. any way to change the settings? and if I did, would it affect a result somehow?

Comment: When setting up the model, you can pass the argument `min_count=1` to override the default of the vocabulary. E.g. `model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)`, see more: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2VecVocab Rare words are unlikely to have a good representation - even for a human it is hard to tell the meaning of a word they have only seen once (for example what's the meaning of "xax" in "I xax every morning.")

Answer (score 0):

If a word you expected to be learned in the model isn't in the model, the most likely causes are:

- it wasn't really there, in the version the model saw, perhaps because your tokenization/preprocessing is broken. Enable logging at INFO level, and examine your corpus as presented to the model, to ensure it's tokenized as intended
- it wasn't part of the surviving vocabulary after the 1st vocabulary-survey of the corpus. The default `min_count=5` discards words with fewer than 5 occurrences, as such words both fail to get good vectors for themselves, and effectively serve as 'noise' interfering with the improvement of other vectors.

You can set `min_count=1` to retain all words, but it's more likely to hurt than help your overall vector quality. Word2Vec & Doc2Vec require large, varied corpuses – if you want a good vector for a word, find more diverse examples of its usage in an expanded corpus.

(Also note: one of the simple & fast `Doc2Vec` modes, that's also often a top-performer, especially on shorter texts, is plain PV-DBOW mode: `dm=0`. This mode will allocate/randomly-initialize word-vectors, but then ignores them for training, **only** training the doc-vectors. If you use that mode, you can still request word-vectors from the model at the end – but they'll just be random nonsense.)